# How to access file of columns with unknown type on RDS database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to upgrade an Aurora PostgreSQL 9.6.19 DB cluster engine to 10 on AWS's RDS management console and it fails giving the following error:

> Database cluster is in a state that cannot be upgraded: Postgres cluster is in a state where pg_upgrade can not be completed successfully.

I read the log on the DB instance and it said:

> Your installation contains the "unknown" data type in user tables. This
> data type is no longer allowed in tables, so this cluster cannot currently
> be upgraded. You can remove the problem tables and restart the upgrade.
> A list of the problem columns is in the file:
> tables_using_unknown.txt

I don't know how to access that file but I executed the following query to find the columns with unknown type:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE data_type ILIKE 'unknown';
```

Then I dropped the columns, tried the upgrade again and it failed with the same error and the same log.

How can I access the file tables_using_unknown.txt?
Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Check these two links. Not exactly your issue but can help. 1: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271672/cannot-upgrade-to-v12-due-to-sql-identifier-data-type  2:https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=291185

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the file but the query that I had run was correct.

The problem was the commands to drop the columns, some worked and others didn't. I'm guessing because the names of the columns were ?column?.

The solution was to drop them using the pgAdmin interface.